# Is it possible to set specific status to be seen by specific user or group in Skype

Tags: skype

You have a regular Skype (v.7.20 right now), not Skype for Business.
What I would like to do is set 'Available' for a specific group of users and 'Do not disturb' for all others.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the skype forum suggests since there does not seems to be such a feature in skype for the moment.

https://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/Can-I-hide-my-online-status-from-specific-contacts/td-p/457705

Summary: block the contacts that you do not want to see you as online and then unblock them since they will have no notification of that.

Comment: Blocking doesn't really solve the question though. Also kind of a pain to do every time you want to change your status

Comment: This is all skype provides for the moment. You can ask at their forum is a change expected or have they come up with some new solution recently.

Comment: It simply doesn't work for me. Blocked account saw updated status (I'm switching from one status to another and blocked account sees new status). I understand, that exiting Skype and starting it again might help, but does not solve the puzzle.

Comment: Than I would suggest using the "Appear offline feature" Or "The RED Phone" and just warn your contacts that should call you that even if the "Appear offline" status is shown you are still there.